# How to extract multiple javascript values from different records at the same level (object not array)

Tags: javascript

I can get at the three values I want with

```
> surfing.surfreport[0].monday["1pm"].tide
5
> surfing.surfreport[0].monday["2pm"].tide
-1
> surfing.surfreport[0].monday["3pm"].tide
-1
>
```

but how can I get all three of those values with one expression.

I tried different selectors and also map operations like

```
> surfing.surfreport[0].monday.map(time => time.tide)
```

but I got

```
Uncaught TypeError: surfing.surfreport[0].monday.map is not a function
```

any individual value but how can I get, say, all the 3 tide values.  Either through my json query or through a js approach

```
surfing = 
{    "surfreport": [
        {
            "beach": "Santa Cruz",
            "monday": {
                "1pm": {
                    "tide": 5,
                    "wind": 15,
                    "watertemp": 80,
                    "surfheight": 5,
                    "recommendation": "Go surfing!"
                },
                "2pm": {
                    "tide": -1,
                    "wind": 1,
                    "watertemp": 50,
                    "surfheight": 3,
                    "recommendation": "Surfing conditions are okay, not great."
                },
                "3pm": {
                    "tide": -1,
                    "wind": 10,
                    "watertemp": 65,
                    "surfheight": 1,
                    "recommendation": "Not a good day for surfing."
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement will create an array of objects, with each object containing `tide`, `wind`, `watertemp`, etc.

```
let reports = Object.values(surfing.surfreport[0].monday);
// [ {tide: 5, wind: 15, ...}, {tide: -1, wind: 1, ...}, ... ]
```

Then, to create an array of just the tide values:

```
let tides = reports.map(obj => obj.tide);
// [ 5, -1, -1 ]
```

Putting it in one statement:

```
let tides = Object.values(surfing.surfreport[0].monday)
                  .map(obj => obj.tide);
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are all good and address your use case, but none of them address the title question.

What if you don't know the intermediate key names (like `surfreport`, `monday`, etc.)?

What if you only know the level you want to extract at?

I wrote a function that does this.

```
(function() {
    let stringified = JSON.stringify(surfing); // your JSON here (in place of surfing)
    let depthTarget = 5; // your target depth level

    let depthCounter = 0;
    let openBracket = /(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\{|\[)/;
    let closedBracket = /(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\}|\])/;
    let openBracketPosition = stringified.search(/(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\{|\[)/);
    let closedBracketPosition = stringified.search(/(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\}|\])/);
    let ourString;
    let done = false;

    function depthSearch() {
        // If an open curly bracket is followed by another open curly bracket,
        if (openBracketPosition !== -1 && stringified.substring(openBracketPosition + 1).search(openBracket) !== -1) {
            depthCounter += 1;
            depthTargetCheck(openBracketPosition, stringified.substring(openBracketPosition + 1).search(openBracket));
        }
        // If an open curly bracket is followed by a closed curly bracket,
        if (openBracketPosition !== -1 && stringified.substring(openBracketPosition + 1).search(closedBracket) !== -1) {
            depthCounter += 1;
            depthTargetCheck(openBracketPosition, stringified.substring(openBracketPosition + 1).search(closedBracket));
        }
        // If a closed curly bracket is followed by another closed curly bracket,
        if (closedBracketPosition !== -1 && stringified.substring(closedBracketPosition + 1).search(closedBracket) !== -1) {
            depthCounter -= 1;
            depthTargetCheck(closedBracketPosition, stringified.substring(closedBracketPosition + 1).search(closedBracket));
        }
        // If a closed curly bracket is followed by an open curly bracket,
        if (closedBracketPosition !== -1 && stringified.substring(closedBracketPosition + 1).search(openBracket) !== -1) {
            depthCounter -= 1;
            depthTargetCheck(closedBracketPosition, stringified.substring(closedBracketPosition + 1).search(openBracket));
        }
        // If we're at the end, i.e., if a closed curly bracket is not followed by any other curly brackets,
        if (closedBracketPosition !== -1 && stringified.substring(closedBracketPosition + 1).search(/(\{|\}|\]|\[)/) === -1) {
            // stop.
            done = true;
        }        
    }

    function depthTargetCheck(firstBracketPosition, secondBracketPosition) {
        // Check if we're at the target level. If we are,
        if (depthCounter === depthTarget) {
            ourString = stringified.substring(firstBracketPosition, secondBracketPosition + 2);
            // If the string is just closed brackets,
            if (ourString.search(/^(\}|\])*$/) !== -1) {
                // return nothing (but don't leave the function).
            } else {
                // If the string begins with a square bracket, i.e., if we're in an array,
                if (ourString.search(/^\[/) !== -1) {
                    // Check if the string ends in an open curly bracket. If it does,
                    if (ourString.search(/\{$/) !== -1) {
                        // replace the ending with a dummy 'object' string, and close off the array.
                        ourString = ourString.replace(/\{$/, '"[object]"]');
                    }
                // If the string ends in a square bracket, i.e., if we're in an array,
                } else if (ourString.search(/\]$/) !== -1) {
                    // Check if the string begins with an open curly bracket. If it does,
                    if (ourString.search(/^\},/) !== -1) {
                        // replace it with an open square bracket.
                        ourString = ourString.replace(/^\},/, '[');
                    }
                } else {
                    // If the last character isn't a closed curly bracket, i.e., if the value is an object or array,
                    if (ourString.charAt(ourString.length - 1) !== '}') {
                        // if the last character is just an open curly bracket,
                        if (ourString.search(/":\{$/) !== -1) {
                            // replace the ending with a dummy 'object' string and close off the JSON.
                            ourString = ourString.replace(/":\{$/, '":"[object]"}');
                        }
                        // if the last character has an open square bracket before it,
                        if (ourString.search(/":(\{|\[)+$/) !== -1) {
                            // replace the ending with a dummy 'array' string and close off the JSON.
                            ourString = ourString.replace(/":(\{|\[)+$/, '":"[array]"}');
                        }
                    }
                    // If the string begins with '},' or '],', i.e., it's not the first key at this level,
                    if (ourString.search(/^(\}|\]),/) !== -1) {
                        // convert it to '{'.
                        ourString = ourString.replace(/^(\}|\]),/, '{');
                    }
                }
                // Fetch the values of 'tide' at the target level.
                console.log(JSON.parse(ourString).tide); // your target key here (if applicable)
                // Or, alternatively, fetch all keys and values at the target level.
                //console.log(JSON.parse(ourString));
            }
        }
        // Continue searching beyond the closed bracket.
        stringified = stringified.substring(secondBracketPosition + 1);
        // Set the new first bracket positions to the new test string.
        openBracketPosition = stringified.search(/(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\{|\[)/);
        closedBracketPosition = stringified.search(/(?<!(\}|\{|\]|\[).*)(\}|\])/);
        depthSearch();
    }
    if (done) {
        return;
    }
    depthSearch();
})();
```

[Runnable version on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_SUM1_/vtyon0z7/19/)

You put the target depth level as the value of `depthTarget`, and you can choose whether to return values for a specific key (like `tide`) or all values at the target level.

All you need is a JSON object and a depth level.

As it is written above, it returns

```
5
-1
-1
```

If you remove the `.tide` from the final `console.log`, it will return all keys and their values at depth level 5:

```
{tide: 5, wind: 15, watertemp: 80, surfheight: 5, recommendation: "Go surfing!"}
{tide: -1, wind: 1, watertemp: 50, surfheight: 3, recommendation: "Surfing conditions are okay, not great."}
{tide: -1, wind: 10, watertemp: 65, surfheight: 1, recommendation: "Not a good day for surfing."}
```

If you then lower the depthTarget to 4, it will return

```
{1pm: "[object]"}
{2pm: "[object]"}
{3pm: "[object]"}
```

A depthTarget of 3 results in

```
{beach: "Santa Cruz", monday: "[object]"}
```

while 2 results in

```
["[object]"]
```

and 1 results in

```
{surfreport: "[array]"}
```

It's not perfect. It will not work if there are square or curly brackets in strings in the object or if the value can't be [JSON.stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (basically, only if it's a function, [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) or `undefined`). Maybe someone (or I) will come around and fix that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can map on an array of properties:

```js
["1pm", "2pm", "3pm"].map(v => surfing.surfreport[0].monday[v].tide);
```

Comment: Change `["1pm", "2pm", "3pm"]` to `Object.keys(surfing.surfreport[0].monday)` and you don't have to know the names ahead of time...